# Can't convert 55cm x 55cm Word doc with many tables & equations to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

I have a word doc with custom page size: 55cm x 55 cm.
I have huge tables drawn into them with a lot of equations.
I am unable to save this doc as pdf (or xps) or print it to pdf. In all cases it simply prepares document with blank pages. Why is this so? How can I convert this document to pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Things which didnt work for me:**

1. File | save As | PDF
2. File | Export | Create PDF/XPS
3. File | Print | Printer | Microsoft Print to PDF
4. Uploading doc to Foxit Word to PDF converter (its conversion process never completed)

All first three resulted PDF with blank pages.

**How I proceeded to fix it further and what eventually worked**

I deleted all of content of doc but kept only first section. (Section can be any logical unit of content, for me it was all paragraphs under single header.) And tried to save it as pdf. It worked!!! I added next section (Do Ctrl+Z to get back whole content and then deleted everything after 2nd section) and tried to save it again as PDF. Worked again. I kept doing it, but for one section it failed. I closely observed it, it had comments. I removed the comments and tried saving as PDF. It worked!!!. So get back to full original content of doc and removed all comments and it was able to save as PDF!!!

Idea was to pin point what is toubling correct PDF generation by successively adding more content before saving as PDF to find out after adding what it fails. When it fails check the newly added content for any suspicious text / character or something like comment.

(I also changed the page margin. I had miniscule page margin of 0.5 cm. But I dont think changing margin did help. Cause it was failing after changing margin. Point is to also try tweaking non-content related parameters.)